# SSH connection with NAnt script

Tags: linux, ssh, nant

Is there a way to make an ssh connection from a windows command line to a Linux machine not using putty?

The Idea is to be able to use NAnt to issue linux commands on the target Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Cygwin ssh client works from the Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to avoid any 3rd party tool besides nant, then no.

Comment: We actually ended up using plink to issue ssh commands from a windows command line.

Comment: I Eneded up using plink.exe from the putty.exe software.
It connects from command line and can execute linux commands from windows command line. U can also separate commands with ";" to get a few commands in one line.